# Facebook Like button in wordpress theme

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I have put a facebook Like button on my 'single.php' page and i am receiving the following error:

The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.

This is my code:

```
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I have also added the following meta tags (with the correct id's):

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="<FB ID HERE>"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<APP ID HERE>" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This one doesnt work either: <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:30px;"></iframe>

Comment: Just a quick question for you but why not you a wordpress extension like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-facebook-like-plugin/ They developers spend a lot of time getting everything to work so i might be easier to use another persons plugin and spend time developing something else and giving that back. Just an idea.

Comment: I also tried that and that gave me the same errors?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the different tips you can find here :
[I Like Button Problem - Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970560/facebook-i-like-button-not-working-all-the-time)

You will find many ways to remove this problem.
I hope it will work for you.